# Reading 20 GB file Using Scapy

Tags: python, networking, wireshark, scapy, pcap

1. I have a *Pcap* file that is **20GB** in size. I want to analyze it using Scapy. My laptop gets hang whenever I want to read it using **Scapy**. Is there anyway to read this file in chunks (few MBs at a time) and then save them in small pcaps files. (Please note that I have a single machine. Don't have big data systems for this problem)
2. How can I get **Session data** from these pcap files using python Scapy. There are multiple flags, ips and ports. How can I take data from each session and store in seperate pcap file.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) installed ([download from the main Wireshark site](https://www.wireshark.org/#download) for Windows and macOS, install from a package for Linux, *BSD, and other UN*Xes not named "macOS"), it comes with an program named [editcap](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) that can, among other things, split a capture file into multiple smaller capture files.

Note that, by default, it writes a pcapng file, not a pcap file, so if Scapy is using its own code to read the file, rather than using libpcap (newer versions of libpcap can read some pcapng files), you may have to specify `-F pcap` as a flag to editcap to get it to write a pcap file.

(Note also that pcap files are *not* text files, so you can't read them "line by line" - there's no such thing as a "line" in a pcap file.  They're not simple to read, so you may be better off using editcap, if possible, rather than writing your own program to read the pcap file.

If you *do* write your own program to read the pcap file, you will probably be better off using libpcap to read it rather than trying to parse the pcap file format yourself.  If you're writing it in Python, see, for example, [pcapy](https://pypi.org/project/pcapy/).)

Answer (score 0):

I can provide some general advice.

[This website](https://www.kroosec.com/2012/10/a-look-at-pcap-file-format.html) describes the format of a PCAP file. According to that website, the format is as follows:

```
Global Header | Header1 | Data1 | Header2 | Data2 | ... | HeaderN | DataN
```

His page explains how to read the Global Header, and using the [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) functions you can read just N bytes from a file, either starting from the beginning or some point further on. You can then break this 20GB file into some number of smaller files, with the smallness based on your available memory.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful to open file and read line by line.